# Embedded Neo4j - Heap memory sizing

Tags: java, neo4j

I am studying the heap memory required by an embedded Neo4j database for storing a "big " graph. I wonder if I can say that the needed heap memory in MB (-Xmx???m) has to be at least:

[image: formula]
with *n* = the number of primitives.

Regards, Brice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the OS you're running it on. If you're using Windows, then the data store is allocated on the heap, but if you're using any Unix system, the data store is mapped to memory outside the heap entirely, and so there's no need to tune the JVM heap for Neo4J specifically.

Comment: Hi Chrylis, thanks for your answer. Is the previous function valid in the case of Windows ?

Comment: @Lambdacrash That depends on your working set. How much of the graph are you expecting to need to access in a short period of time? That equation is a reasonable estimate as long as you remember that string values aren't primitives.

Comment: I just wonder if my function is valid regarding the table describing the Heap configuration (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/configuration-jvm.html). I know that the heap usage will be impacted by the number of queries on the graph, the size of properties, etc. I just want to find a lower bound of the Heap for Windows OS.